# Why are the options for PID control commented out in Klipper config file?

Tags: klipper, pid, tronxy

I have a Tronxy VEHO-600 I'm currently vamping up with Klipper. I have a config file I got from a friend for a modified VEHO-600. My question is regarding the heater bed code block seen below:

```
[heater_bed]
heater_pin: PE2
sensor_type: EPCOS 100K B57560G104F
sensor_pin: PC2
min_temp: 0
max_temp: 150
#control: pid
#pid_Kp: 73.932
#pid_Ki: 1.521
#pid_Kd: 898.279
```

Why are all the options for PID commented out? Is this only active when PID tuning? Also, what are the numerical values?

Answer (score 2):

When you save the PID values after auto-tuning, Klipper will put the new values in a special section **at the end of the config file** that looks like this:

```
#*# <---------------------- SAVE_CONFIG ---------------------->
#*# DO NOT EDIT THIS BLOCK OR BELOW. The contents are auto-generated.
#*#
#*#
#*# [extruder]
#*# control = pid
#*# pid_kp = 25.957
#*# pid_ki = 1.466
#*# pid_kd = 114.858
```

While these lines look like comments, Klipper will actually load and use them, as described in the issue [PID Tuning values not stored correctly?](https://github.com/Klipper3d/klipper/issues/719).

Answer (score 1):

This PID options are commented out, because they are not currently being used. Klipper allows for different heating algorithms, and PID control is just one of them.
If no control option is specified in the config file, Klipper will use Bang-Bang control as the default heating algorithm for the heated bed.

The numerical values in the commented out lines (`pid_Kp`, `pid_Ki`, `pid_Kd`) are the PID tuning parameters, which are specific to each printer and must be tuned to achieve stable temperature control.

If you were to uncomment these lines, Klipper would use PID control to manage the temperature of the heated bed, and the numerical values would need to be adjusted through a tuning process to optimize the performance of the PID controller for your printer.